# PHP array displays values within HTML tags but not in CSS selectors (Wordpress)?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm following [this](http://vimeo.com/14470991) tutorial to create custom Wordpress options

the function within theme/functions/admin-menu.php which changes the background color:

```
// Color Scheme
function color_scheme_setting() {
   $options = get_option('plugin_options');
   $items = array("Red", "Green", "Blue");

   echo "<select name='plugin_options[color_scheme]'>";
   foreach ($items as $item) {
      $selected = ( $options['color_scheme'] === $item ) ? 'selected = "selected"' : '';
      echo "<option value='$item' $selected>$item</option>";
   }
   echo "</select>";
}
```

header.php:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: <?php echo $options['color_scheme']; ?>
    }
</style>

</head>



<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
        </h1>

        <?php $options = get_option('plugin_options'); ?>
        <h2> <?php echo $options['banner_heading']; ?> </h2>
        <img src="<?php echo $options['logo']; ?>" alt='' />
        <p><?php echo $options['color_scheme']; ?></p>

        <div id="lang">
            <?php do_action('icl_language_selector'); ?>
            <?php _e( 'english', 'starkers' ); ?>
        </div>

        <ul id="nav">
            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
        </ul>
```

When I select "green" in the dashboard, `$options['color_scheme']` in the background selector doesn't appear.

(but it does appear in `$options['color_scheme']` inside the `<p>` tags

Any suggestions to make this array work in the background selector?

(I'm using Wordpress 3.03)

**EDIT:**

I just tried this:

```
    <p style="color: <?php echo $options['color_scheme']; ?>"><?php echo $options['color_scheme']; ?></p>
```

and the `<p>` tag changed its color

Why it doesn't work between the `<style>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$options` variable is only initialized after your `<h1>` element is rendered. Its value is not available yet when you want to use it in the `<style>` block.

You might want to initialize that variable earlier:

```
<?php $options = get_option('plugin_options'); ?>
<style>
    body {
        background: <?php echo $options['color_scheme']; ?>
    }
</style>
```